Eclipse maven error: SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found
When i run in command window my test cases running.
Command used: mvn clean verify
But when i run directly from eclipse it throws below error.
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J(W): Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J(W): Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/XXX/YYYY/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.1.20211008-0657/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.

I added slf4j-api and changed ch.qos.logback version to 1.2.11. still getting same error when running in eclipse: Eclipse>right click> run as >maven build


Is there any output before or after that?

Have you actually read that link in the error message?

Do your tests fail, though? These look more like Warnings to stderr.

This looks very much like an issue that was fixed some time ago. Please make sure that you are using the latest version of Eclipse. Otherwise, please tell how this can this be reproduced in the current version.

The link clearly states which version of (for instance) Logback should be used. It's not in line with what you think it is
